# multiprocessing in threads in python doesn't make every child process work

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

When executing a child processes in each threads with `threading` module in python, some of the processes don't properly start and hang up like the output of sample code.

That seems like launching a process needs exclusive control because of IPC in python. Is it right?

With threading lock, it works perfectly. I just wanted to make a thread to control a child process for its life and death management.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fenc=utf-8

import multiprocessing
import threading

import fire
from logzero import logger


def process_method():
    logger.info("process log")


def start_process():
    logger.info("starting thread")
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_method)
    process.daemon = True
    process.start()
    process.join()


def main(num_of_threads=3):
    threads = []
    for _ in range(num_of_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_process)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    logger.info("program done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fire.Fire(main)
```

### The output

```
$ python '/tmp/tmp.lY3YDIltYg/test.py' 30
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:20] starting thread
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
[I 190822 09:10:38 test:16] process log
```

### Environment

- python 3.6
- ubutu 64bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a UNIX-like system? Because if so, you're doing bad things here; [mixing `fork` with threads is a bad idea](https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them), and Python's default implementation of `Process` on UNIX-like systems uses `fork`, so by starting `Process`es in a thread, you're `fork`ing from a multithreaded process.

There are two solutions here:

1. Stop using threads. Your threads aren't necessary here, since they don't actually manage lifetime (both thread and process are `daemon`s, so they'll be unceremoniously killed when the main thread of the main process finishes).
2. If you must use threads, and you're on Python 3.4+, you can switch [to the fork-server start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) (or the `'spawn'` method to make your code portable to Windows, at the expense of making `Process` creation a little slower on UNIX-like systems), so the only `fork` from your main process is done before you launch any threads, and all future `fork`s are done from the (threadless) fork server. All you do is add `multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')` as the first line after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard.

Comment: Side-note: I have no idea how `fire` or `logzero` are implemented, so it's entirely possible they're either not thread safe or not `fork` safe. You may want to try simplifying to Python built-ins here if you continue having problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, that's under Linux OS. That makes sense.